# Hide the item with jQuery if the data returned from PHP is empty

Tags: php, jquery

After pulling data from PHP, if the data returns empty, I want to hide that element with jQuery. For example, military service information should not be displayed for those whose gender is female.

```
<div class="form-group" id="cinsiyet">
    <label class="d-inline">Cinsiyet</label>
    <select class="d-inline" name="cinsiyet_id" >
        <option value="<?= $user_bilgisi_listesi->cinsiyet_id ?>"><?= $user_bilgisi_listesi->cinsiyet_ad ?></option>
        <option value="1">Erkek</option>
        <option value="2">Kadın</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="askerlik">
    <label class="d-inline">Askerlik Durumu</label>
    <select class="d-inline" name="askerlikdurumu_id" >
        <option value="<?= $user_bilgisi_listesi->askerlikdurumu_id ?>"><?= $user_bilgisi_listesi->askerlikdurumu_ad ?></option>
        <option value="1">Yapıldı</option>
        <option value="2">Tecilli</option>
        <option value="3">Muaf</option>
        <option value="4">Yapılıyor</option>
        <option value="5">Askerlik Çağına Gelmemiş</option>
        <option value="6">Diğer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't need it responsive to user actions, you can do it with PHP, and no need for jQuery. An `if` statement in PHP will do the trick.

Comment: _"if the data returns empty, I want to hide that element"_ - what data? What element? Currently quite unclear what you are talking about here.

Comment: __Military service information should not be displayed for those whose gender is female.__: In your given code sample we are unable to find out that

Comment: I want to hide the military dropdown when user selects female from gender dropdown. This process needs to be dynamic.

Comment: This snippet is only part of the program. "<?= $user_info_list->gender_id ?>" is a query from the database in this section.

Comment: The gender information of the user changes according to the session information. For a female user who has entered data about their gender before, I want their military information to be hidden when they open the page.

Answer (score -2):

Yuo can use Ajax resquest to get de result from PHP and verify his content.

check: [Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: In this case, with jQuery you can do a http request and work with the response data like status code, payload, headers and more.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer, maybe it was better you would write some lines of code showing how to do that